# Replace dynamic alphanumeric string in perl script

Tags: regex, perl

can any body help me with the below search and replace in perl script?

```
my $str="3Y56";
my $string1 = "hld_io_custodian_92Z0_mthly.param";
print $string1;
```

I want the output as "hld_io_custodian_3Y56_mthly.param".

Note that 3Y56 and 92Z0 both are dynamic strings and can be different everytime.
Every time the 4 digit value after "hld_io_custodian_" must be replaced by the new 4 digit alphanumeric string"

Comment: Is it always after `hld_io_custodian_` which is the string start?

Comment: What have you tried? What issues are you having? Please show use your attempts.

Answer (score 3):

You can use substitution:

```
$string1 =~ s/hld_io_custodian_\K.{4}/\Q$str/;
```

(`\K` means "forget everything up to here" and was introduced in Perl 5.10.)

Or, if the strings are of the same length every time, use [substr](http://p3rl.org/substr)

```
substr $string1, 17, 4, $str;
```